# Need to Append multiple values form list into a key Dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, dictionary, bioinformatics

I have created a dictionary with empty values as "dictionary". I also have a list named contig_list_numbers(first list in the output) . What i have been trying to do is to append the  values from contig_list_numbers into the 
the dictionary values.

what i want is to place all string values after ":" in list as the values in the dictionary.ex- contig1000:254', 'contig1000:170', 'contig1000:1114', 'contig1000:2199' this to be converted into {contig1000 : [254,170,1114,2199]}
can someone help me out ??

[first list is contig_list_numbers 
last is dictionary with empty values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkzJA.png)

Comment: You may want to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'll go through it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string by `:` to get `key` and `value`, store them to `dictionary`
and append the value if key already exist.
So the solution would be:

```
dictionary = {}
contig_list_numbers = ['contig1000:254', 'contig1000:170', 'contig1000:1114', 'contig1000:2199']

for astring in contig_list_numbers:
    key, value = astring.split(":")
    if key not in dictionary:
        dictionary[key] = [value]
    else:
        dictionary[key].append(value)
```

Comment: This worked!!!! I was trying loop through values and keys separately which caused lot of errors . Thank you for your help. Earlier i was typing "dictionary[key].append[value]" . This was the error right ??

Comment: Yes. Glad it helped :)